# Serialize the List<string> value within a Dictionary<string, List<string>> as simple array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the Mongo .Net Driver 2.7.2, I am attempting to customize how a Dictionary property is getting serialized.  Specifically, I would like the Dictionary's value, a `List<string>` to serialize as a simple array.

**Current document structure generated by serializer**

This is how the property is currently serializing.  As you can see, `someProperty`is being serialized as an object, with _t and _v storing the `.NET` type and value.

```
viewedBy: Object
    someProperty: Object
        _t: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
        _v: Array
```

I understand the type information is stored for deserialization back into the c# POCO, but for my case I don't need this metadata, as my type is just a string array.

**Desired document structure**

I would like the property values to serialize as simple arrays of strings,as below

```
viewedBy: Object
    someProperty: Array
```

Here is the class I am attempting to customize the serialization strategy for.

```cs
public class MyDocument
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> ViewedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**Current Mapping**

Here is the mapping information I have provided for my class.

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyDocument>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();

            cm.MapMember(c => c.ViewedBy)
              .SetElementName("viewedBy")
              .SetSerializer(new 
           DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<string, 
              List<string>>>(DictionaryRepresentation.Document));

           // How do I specify the dictionary value should serialize as simple array?
        });
```

**Question**

How can I instruct the serializer to serialize the dictionary's value, of `.NET` type `List<string>` to serialize into a simple string array?

Preference is for a fluent mapping solution, rather than using Attributes.

Comment: are you open to linq?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by this. Using Linq for which part?

Comment: To convert `public Dictionary<string, List<string>>` ---> `Array`

Comment: I am comfortable doing so with Linq, however my question is specifically regarding serialization/deserialization through the MongoDb driver.  I want to instruct the driver how to represent my property in the mongo database.  For example, there is a method provided to instruct the driver how to handle the serialization of `enums`, as described here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/#enums

Comment: You want values of all the keys in a single array?

Comment: I want the document to be serialized so that `viewedBy.someProperty` is stored as an array inside the database, and not as an object with _t and _v properties.  See the 'Current Document Structure' and 'Desired Document Structure' sections in my question

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you said. But still check it

Answer (score 0):

Include `System.Linq`
use this the way you want.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> m = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
m.Add("1", new List<string> { "Sumit", "Raj" });
m.Add("2", new List<string> { "Rahul", "Raj" });

/*Array of string. Currently 4 values*/
var res = m.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToArray();

/*Array of List<string>. Currently 2 List With 2 Values*/
var res1 = m.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Again:

How can I instruct the serializer to serialize the dictionary's value, of .NET type List<string> to serialize into a simple string array?

Comment: May be you can extend a method which uses `Dictionary` to give you the `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of **DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer** with specifying serializer for key and value:

```
            var mySerializer = new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<string, List<string>>, string, List<string>>(
            dictionaryRepresentation: DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments,
            keySerializer: BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<string>(),
            valueSerializer: BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<List<string>>());
```

then just use the "mySerializer" instance when mapping the element "myView" using .SetSerializer(mySerializer).
Credits go to [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458792)