# Bson Serialization Error Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization

Hi everyone I have a problem. The my problem is can not serialize bson document dictionary of dictionary. How can i serialize bson document dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<Symbols, Dictionary<int, decimal>> SymbolCoinRates { get; set; } 
  = new();
```

Error message is like below

> MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: When using
> DictionaryRepresentation.Document key values must serialize as
> strings.    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.SerializeKeyString(TKey key)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.SerializeDocumentRepresentation(BsonSerializationContext
> context, TDictionary value)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.SerializeValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TDictionary value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ClassSerializerBase`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext
> context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TValue value)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, TValue value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.SerializeArrayOfDocumentsRepresentation(BsonSerializationContext
> context, TDictionary value)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.SerializeValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TDictionary value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ClassSerializerBase`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext
> context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TValue value)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, Object value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeNormalMember(BsonSerializationContext
> context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeMember(BsonSerializationContext context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeClass(BsonSerializationContext
> context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TClass document)    at
> MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TClass value)    at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1
> serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, TValue value)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.OperatorUpdateDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1
> documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry,
> LinqProvider linqProvider)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.CombinedUpdateDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1
> documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry,
> LinqProvider linqProvider)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ConvertWriteModelToWriteRequest(WriteModel`1
> model, Int32 index)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation..ctor(CollectionNamespace collectionNamespace, IEnumerable`1 requests, MessageEncoderSettings
> messageEncoderSettings)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateBulkWriteOperation(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWriteAsync(IClientSessionHandle session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2
> funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1
> filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3
> bulkWriteAsync)    at
> Dev360.Domain.Context.MongoDb`1.UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition`1
> filter, Func`2 update, UpdateOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Dev360\SlotBase\Core\Dev360.Domain\Context\MongoDbRepository.cs:line 110    at Dev360.GameEngine.Api.Features.Commands.Modes.GameModeCommandHandler.Handle(GameModeCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Dev360\SlotBase\Apis\Dev360.GameEngine.Api\Features\Commands\Modes\GameModeCommand.cs:line 43    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)    at Dev360.GameEngine.Api.Controllers.ModesController.UpdateAsync(GameModeCommand gameModeCommand) in C:\Dev360\SlotBase\Apis\Dev360.GameEngine.Api\Controllers\ModesController.cs:line 48    at lambda_method561(Closure , Object )    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: */* Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:7266 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Authorization: Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImN0eSI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjc2NvZGUiOiJMTEFJIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJHdWVzdC4iLCJuYmYiOjE2NTk0NDQwMzIsImV4cCI6MTY2MDA0ODgzMiwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NDQ0MDMyLCJpc3MiOiJEZXYzNjAuU2xvdC5BcGkiLCJhdWQiOiJEZXYzNjAuU2xvdCJ9.fmT2z84YT3gZVZX04JrU0c95btGhLFJqgkSb2yHnGDM
> Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json traceparent:
> 00-68a5cd84c23d6cd77b2f35eb5712ef80-c8bb294477e2b897-00
> Content-Length: 3556 Postman-Token:
> c7907ebe-e340-402e-b438-eb5e83ca1564 ApplicationId: AppId
> ApplicationType: AppType ExchangeId: ExchangeId UserId: LLAI

Its solved
I search so much for a solution but I dont find a solution. Because I seperate dictionary of dictionary array to in new class and two property. One prorety is Symbol type and other property is dictioary proprerty.

```
public class SymbolCoinRate
{
    public Symbols Symbol { get; set; }
    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)] 
    public Dictionary<int,decimal> CoinRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the error message as text. This makes it easier for others to read.

Comment: I added error message text @Markus :)

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28111846/642579 I think the issue is the `Symbols` key in your dictionary.